# When is it ok to have two different layouts for the same page inside a web application?

Tags: web-app, user-behavior, applications

I have a page inside the application that will be displayed inside a popup on other page. Since the page was not designed for the popup size I wanted to create a compact view for it. Would this be confusing to users who are already used to regular view of that page?

Comment: Give us more details. Are the users interacting with the content inside the popup? If not I would display only what's relevant to users seeing the popup version. Hopefully once you take out some of the content and functionality the page will be different enough not to create confusion.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Also is this a popup or a modal dialog?

Answer (score 3):

Using the exact same layout would probably look redundant. Aside from that, pop-up windows are smaller in size and chances are you'll have to heavily reformat the information previously placed on an entire page anyways being that a compact view of a web page may get cluttered. If it is vital to re-introduce the information from a page into a pop up window, consider reformatting and reducing to be a reminder, otherwise linking to the page would be common practice.